# Filtering on join or where? Whats the difference?

Tags: mysql, sql, pgadmin

If i filter on join I get this as result:
[filtering on join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9E4O.png)

and If I filter on where
[Filtering on where](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTh47.png)

Why do I get a difference result?
What's the difference?
When I need to use the filter in join and when i need to use the filter in where?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the difference is the use of a `LEFT JOIN` .

When you're specifying the filters on the `RIGHT` table of a `LEFT JOIN` inside the `WHERE` clause , then join transforms into an `INNER JOIN` due to `NULL` comparison.

Filters on the right table should **always** and only be specified inside the `ON` clause .

Comment: No because its with inner join too.